# How to convert a String to a searchable Array in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a String like `Lion is the king` I need to split it in such a way that it returns an array **like this** :

```
L
Li
Lio
Lion
""
i
is
""
t
th
the
""
k
ki
kin
king
```

**My CODE** :

```
List<String> splitList = name.split(' ');
List<String> indexList = [];
for (int i = 0; i < splitList.length; i++,) {
  for (int j = 0; j < splitList[i].length; j++) {
    indexList.add(splitList[i].substring(0, j).toLowerCase());
  }
}
return indexList;
```

Here `name` is a *String*.

**Result of the above code**:

```
L
Li
Lio
""
i
""
t
th
""
k
ki
kin
```

**Problem with my code** :

In my code the last alphabet of every word is missing.

**Uses of this**:

I am using this for *searching* purposes, in short I am saving this `array` in `Firestore` and create a searching function using `array contains:` in `StreamBuilder`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first element of your `j` loop is using `word.substring(0, 0) or ''.

This is why the result of your method contains an empty string before each word split:

```
[, l, li, lio, , i, , t, th, , k, ki, kin, king]
```

Your code with correction:

```
List<String> indexString(String name) {
  List<String> splitList = name.split(' ');
  List<String> indexList = [];
  for (int i = 0; i < splitList.length; i++,) {
    for (int j = 0; j < splitList[i].length; j++) {
      indexList.add(splitList[i].substring(0, j + 1).toLowerCase());
    }
  }
  return indexList;
}
```

But, you'll also have a problem with punctuation.

- **Input:** `"Lion, he is the king!"`
- **Output:** `["l", "li", "lio", "lion", "lion,", "h", "he", "i", "is", "t", "th", "the", "k", "ki", "kin", "king", "king!"]`

---

### RegExp

Maybe you should use [Regular Expressions](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/RegExp-class.html).

```
void main() {
  final name = "Lion, he is the king!";
  print(indexString(name));
}

List<String> indexString(String name) {
  RegExp regExp = new RegExp(r"(\w+)");
  List<String> splitList =
      regExp.allMatches(name).map((m) => m.group(0)).toList();
  print(splitList);
  List<String> indexList = splitList
      .map(
        (word) => word.split('').fold<List<String>>(
          [''],
          (acc, curr) => [...acc, '${acc.last}$curr'],
        ).sublist(1),
      )
      .expand((i) => i)
      .toList();
  return indexList;
}
```

*Note: This will also index alphanumeric words.*

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, in my case I will not need the RegExp as the String i am splitting dosen't contain any punctuation or alphanumeric.

Answer (score 1):

By adding one to the splitList[i].length it should works:

```
String name = "Lion is the king";
List<String> splitList = name.split(' ');
List<String> indexList = [];
for (int i = 0; i < splitList.length; i++,) {
  for (int j = 0; j < splitList[i].length + 1; j++) {
    indexList.add(splitList[i].substring(0, j).toLowerCase());
  }
}
for (var element in indexList){
 print("\n $element");
}
//return indexList
```

Comment: This solution has two drawbacks: [1] `indexList` contains empty strings, and [2] it also indexes punctuation characters.

Answer (score 1):

use `split` to every char

```
    String name = "Lion is the king";
    var res = List<String>();
    var word = '';
    
    name.split('').forEach((char) {
      word = (char.isEmpty) ?  '': word + char.toLowerCase();
      res.add(word);
    });

    print(res);
```

output:

```
[l, li, lio, lion, , i, is, , t, th, the, , k, ki, kin, king]
```